# Save .mp4 from YouTube output stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am currently running a **Ffmpeg** script in **Raspbian** which works fine. It captures video from an USB webcam and stream it to YouTube.

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec aac -ab 128k -strict experimental -aspect 16:9 -vcodec h264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -vb 820k -maxrate 820k -bufsize 820k -profile:v baseline -r 30 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX-XXX-XXX
```

But I also want to save the file into an mp4 file.

I have tried adding a .mp4 file to the end, but it generates a corrupt file and the stream does not emit at 1x speed, it get slower to 0.4x

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec aac -ab 128k -strict experimental -aspect 16:9 -vcodec h264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -vb 820k -maxrate 820k -bufsize 820k -profile:v baseline -r 30 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX-XXX-XXX output.mp4
```

I have also tried without result:

```
-vcodec copy -acodev copy output.mp4
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Use the [tee](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs#Teepseudo-muxer) muxer.

Comment: Any example with my source code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 30 -aspect 16:9 -c:v h264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -maxrate:v 820k -bufsize:v 820k -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental -flags +global_header -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX-XXX-XXX|video.flv"
```

Comment: Well, it seems to work but... my Rpi 3 CPUS and RAM are at 100%. Can we solve this without transcoding or optimizing it?

Comment: The streams are being encoded only once. The FLV file isn't triggering a 2nd encode. You could change the preset to `superfast`.

Comment: Its an improvement. Bug muy saved FLV is not seekable. Is any metadata missing?

Comment: FLV is a streaming format. You can quickly remux it to MP4: `ffmpeg -i in.flv -c copy out.mp4`

Comment: Aham, it seems to work but unfortunatelly, i am experiencing CPU and RAM issues again, so my video isn't fluid. Now i am trying to replicate this command with a Raspicam using raspivid and avconv, and adding a logo too. This is my currrent raspivid command: `raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | avconv -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 50 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX`

Comment: And here my working ffmpeg USB cam: `ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -f v4l2 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 -map 0:v -map 1:a -r 30 -aspect 16:9 -c:v h264 -preset veryfast -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -maxrate:v 820k -bufsize:v 820k -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental -flags +global_header -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5 [out]" -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX|video.flv"` . **Can i stream put logo and save to disc using raspivid?**